# position fixed doesnt display css

Tags: html, css

for a school project i have to use position fixed and get the cookie statement right bottom on the screen. If I try to move the element doesnt even display.

```css
.cookie {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #FA0;
}

.cookie-text {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cookie">
  <p class="cookie-text">Cookie statement </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set an element's `top, bottom, left, and right` positions, you're pinning to that exact spot. Since you're setting each position to `0%` (which really should just be `0`), you're taking up the entire screen.

If you want the element on the right bottom, just set the `right` and `bottom` values.

Also, you don't need the float since the element is fixed. If you want to ensure the cookie statement sits on top of other elements, add a `z-index` property with a high value.

Something like the following should work:

```
.cookie {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 50%;
  background-color: #FA0;
  z-index: 100; // or some other value > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `top` and `Left` in your CSS.

```css
.cookie {
  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0;

  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #FA0;
}

.cookie-text {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cookie">
  <p class="cookie-text">Cookie statement </p>
</section>
```

Comment: `float: right` remove too.